# How to use a software installed by "cargo install" (Rust)

Tags: terminal, command-line, install, homebrew, big-sur

I installed with `brew install rust`, which also installed `cargo` command. On the Rust homepage they offer a different installation method, but I like to keep everything managed by Homebrew.

I then installed [`cargo install tickrs`](https://github.com/tarkah/tickrs#installation), but could not start the software `tickrs`. Even in new Terminal window, it seems some path issue.

```
tickrs -s BTC-EUR
zsh: command not found: tickrs

echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is really best to stick with one package manager then your setup will work.

Homebrew if it build tickes would put that in a directory which is on your path.

You are using cargo now so you need another directory on your path. That is `~/.cargo/bin` if Homebrew has installed the standard cargo.

I just had to go through this for Apple Silicon on Big Sur as there isn't a release build of rust yet. The cargo documents make this hard to find. Possibly becaus of another comment that cargo builds will not update when upstream changes are made as would happen with a package manager (e.g. HomeBrew) So I suspect cargo is not meant for your use just for those developing in rust.